# grepl across multiple columns in R

Tags: r, regex

I have the following data which has n.a. values (which R does not recognise)

I am trying to remove these values using `grepl`

```
x <- x[!grepl("n.a.", x$Fixed.assets.EUR.Last.avail..yr),]
```

but I am trying to apply it across all columns instead of specifying each column name and having many lines of text.

What I currently have is

```
x <- sapply(x[, c(1:4)], !grepl("n.a."))
```

which produces errors and does not work.

```
Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
  '!grepl("n.a.", x[, 1:4])' is not a function, character or symbol
```

Data

```
dput(x)[1:6, ]
  Fixed.assets.EUR.Last.avail..yr Fixed.assets.EUR.Year...1 Fixed.assets.EUR.Year...2
1                      34,827,809                38,549,311                29,035,369
2                         755,256                   658,200                   573,888
3                       2,639,824                 2,739,205                 3,230,890
4                       2,543,367                 2,317,132                 2,994,769
5                       1,608,004                 1,702,838                 1,763,244
6                         661,875                   661,082                   584,166
  Fixed.assets.EUR.Year...3
1                30,416,099
2                      n.a.
3                 2,841,046
4                   693,370
5                 2,024,666
6                   565,007
```

Comment: What do you mean by: "trying to remove these values"? Remove row?

Comment: you need to tal of `sapply(x[,1:4],grepl,pattern="n.a.")` or  `sapply(x[,1:4],function(x)grepl("n.a.",x))`

Comment: I do not see how you get your data into R, but many functions to read input files, like read.table() have a parameter:  na.strings = "NA". This one you can use to define your own NA,  na.strings = "n.a." right at the reading step

Comment: I am trying to remove the row values yes, and regarding the import of na values. I actually want to keep the na values as the dataset is much larger than the 4 columns I include here and removing them will cause me to lose a lot of information across other columns.

Comment: Onyambu: Running your commands just returns a TRUE/FALSE dataframe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me start by saying that the best practice here would be to specify a `na.strings = c("n.a.")` argument when you read in your data. That said, this is a way to use `grepl()` to remove any row where you have `n.a.` as a string.

```
x[-which(apply(x[,1:4],1,function(y) any(grepl("n.a.",y, fixed=TRUE)))),]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want R to recognize "n.a." as NA values without removing the entire row (and hence losing real values across a row with an n.a. value in only one column), you can use this:

```
df[df=="n.a."] <- NA
```

Otherwise, you are better off using @Mako212's solution.

Comment: And this is not a bad step regardless of whether you're going to remove NA values following a solution like mine. It's not good to have "false NAs" floating around in your data unless you need to differentiate between a "n.a." value in your data (i.e. as a factor level), and a `NA` value in R.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 alternative options

Example Data

```
set.seed(1)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c("n.a.", "good"), 20, replace=TRUE), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE))
head(df)

    # V1   V2
# 1 n.a. n.a.
# 2 good good
# 3 n.a. good
# 4 good good
# 5 good n.a.
# 6 n.a. n.a.
```

Convert `n.a.` to `NA`, then use `complete.cases`

```
data <- replace(df, df == "n.a.", NA)
data[complete.cases(data),]

    # V1   V2
# 2 good good
# 4 good good
# 9 good good
```

Use `rowSums`

```
df[rowSums(df == "n.a.") == 0,]

    # V1   V2
# 2 good good
# 4 good good
# 9 good good
```